# Is there a way i can write css attributes targeted specifically for IE8,7,6 in a CSS file

Tags: css

I want to uses some css attibutes only for IE 6,7,8 in a css file. is it possible?
Is it possible to target specific version of IE  for each attribute.

somthing like this:

```
.mystyle {
   top:5px
   top:-30px //only if ie6
   top:-5px  //only if ie8
}
```

i know about `<![If lt IE7]>` tags but, i dont want to create one more css file.

Comment: Yes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script is tiny, and filled with awesome:  http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

It will put classes on the HTML element that correspond to the user's browser.  That will let you do things like this:

```
.ie7 .mystyle { top:5px;}
.ie8 .mystyle { top:-30px;}
```

I wouldn't create a new external javascript file just for this script.  Its so small that I usually just add it to the top of my existing external javascript file.

Comment: that's a decent solution to this problem +1! - updated my answer to be clever like this && not javascript reliant

Comment: Wow i liked this solution:). @Inrbob : I liked your solution too. In normal case i would have preferred your solution not to use js! but unfortunately i have many html files and i don't want to edit all of them.

Answer (score 3):

there are a number of hacks you can use in your stylesheets themselves but this is generally considered bad practise. Here is [an example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/)

Why don't you want to use multiple stylesheets?

inspired by Stephen's post you could do this (stolen from [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) by paul irish):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

**Final edit**

should explain. If you add this to the html you will conditionally set an IE overriding class. The final line renders no class if browser is greater than IE9 (none) or not IE

Comment: I like the HTML5 Boilerplate solution.  Very similar to what my answer does.  +1 for not relying on JS.  However, if a greater degree of flexibility is required (like targeting a particular browser like FF3 or Chrome) you'll need to use something like JavaScript.

Comment: quite right! Fortunately those fixes are generally more rare and often less of an issue when js is disabled :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE hacks, which will achieve what you're looking for. However, it's not advised to do that; long term maintenance will become difficult.

The conditional comments solution is the easiest and cleanest solution, and it's supported by MS. You should use them.